# Subfields of algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F_n$ denote the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, in which every integer-coefficient polynomial of degree $\leq n$ factorizes completely into linear factors.

It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}=F_1\subseteq\dots\subseteq F_n\subseteq F_{n+1}\subseteq\ldots\subseteq F_\infty$, where $F_\infty:=\bigcup\limits_n F_n$ is the field of algebraic numbers. Further let $R_n:=F_n\cap R$, where $R$ is the field of all algebraic numbers that are expressible in terms of radicals. Galois theory shows that $F_n\neq R_n$ for $n\geq 5$.

I'm interested in learning more about the structure of $F_n$. E.g. is $F_{n+1}$ an infinite extension of $F_n$? Is $F_n$ an infinite extension of $R_n$? Is $R_{n+1}\neq R_n$? Is $F_{n+1}\backslash R\neq F_n\backslash R$?

I do not immediately find literature on this and it is not immediately clear to me how difficult such questions are. Have they been studied? I'd expect that one just needs to know where to look.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? What progress have you made and where did you get stuck?

Comment: $[R_6:R_5]$ seems non-trivial and interesting.

Comment: By Kummer theory $F_2=R_2/F_1=R_1=\mathbb{Q}$ is obtained by adjoining all square roots of reps of $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$ hence is not finite degree. Maybe a similar argument would should show $R_{i+1}/R_i$ is of infinite degree after noting that $\mu_{i + 1} \subset R_i$. Perhaps this could be extended to $F_{i+1}/F_i$